# Find an Employee by Name and throw a custom Exception if the given name was not Found

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-stream

I am trying to prepare an employee search program.

*Requirements:*

- I have an `ArrayList` "employee" which is holding data of multiple employees (*like : `name`, `employeeID`, `location`, `DOJ`, etc*).
- I need to prepare a method to say `findEmployee` which will expect a `name` as input, and will return all the associated details with that employee.
- In case no such *employee* was found, then it should throw an exception.

*My code*:

```
private static List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();

public Employee findEmployee(String Name) throws emplyeeNotFoundException {

    for(Employee value : employee) {
        if(value.getName().equals(Name)) {
            return value;
        }
        else {
            throw new emplyeeNotFoundException(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `Employee` is the main class and `getName()` is the method to get the name of employee.

***Issue:***

- I am aware that above logic will not work as it will throw an exception every time `if` condition does not meet the requirement.

Can anyone suggest to me how I need to write this code so that it will check the complete employee list and only throw an exception when no data found?

Also, if it found the employee name in `ArrayList` it should return all its details and come out of the loop?

Comment: Java naming conventions would tell you to replace `String Name` with `String name` - classes generally get capitalized first letter, variable names do not. Also `emplyeeNotFoundException` should be changed to `EmplyeeNotFoundException` since it's a class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it will throw an exception every time if condition does not meet the requirement

No, that's not correct. An *exception* will be thrown only **once** if the very first employee in the list has a *name* which is different from the target name.

The method will be deallocated from the *stack*, i.e. its execution will be terminated. And *exception* will be propagated to the calling method. If the caller will not be able to handle it, the *exception* will be propagated further.

To prevent it, you need to place the `throws` clause outside the loop:

```
public Employee findEmployee(String Name) throws emplyeeNotFoundException {
    
    Employee result = null;
    
    for (Employee value : employee) {
        if (value.getName().equals(Name)) {
            result = value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        throw new emplyeeNotFoundException(Name);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In my personal opinion, it's better to avoid returning from the middle of the method. It makes the code more structured and easier to read.

And since you've specified the tag [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) here another solution using Stream API.

#### Stream-based solution

You can use apply [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) with your condition and then [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) as a terminal operation, which will produce an optional result `Optional<Employee>`.

And finally, apply [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)) on the optional object, that will either retrieve the employee or will throw an exception if optional is empty.

One of the flavors on `orElseThrow()` expects a supplier as an argument, so we can the *exception* that be thrown if result wasn't found.

```
return employee.stream()
    .filter(emp -> emp.getName().equals(name))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new EmplyeeNotFoundException(name));
```

*Sidenote:*

- adhere to the [*Java naming conventions*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) when you're giving names to your classes, methods, etc. Names of classes should start with a *capital letter*  - `EmplyeeNotFoundException`, and variable-name with a *lower case letter* - `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception after looping over the whole array (meaning you didn't find any employees), and if you do find one, the function will return.

```java
private static List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();

public Employee findEmployee(String Name) throws emplyeeNotFoundException {
  for(Employee value : employee) {
    if (value.getName().equals(Name)) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  throw new emplyeeNotFoundException(Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Employee findEmployee(String Name) throws emplyeeNotFoundException {
    boolean isFound = false;
    for(Employee value : employee) {
        if(value.getName().equals(Name)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    throw new emplyeeNotFoundException(Name); 
}
```

If the value is present, returns the value.
If not present, the loop ends and at this point nothing is returned. Hence the Exception is thrown.